# Why do i receive an empty or null array on my GET route with express and sqlite3

Tags: csv, express, import, sqlite

for a challenge i had to create a server. I imported three csv files and made an express app. every-time i run node to get back the JSON, i receive an empty array.

````
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.sqlite')

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on Port 3000 '))

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let stmt = []
    db.serialize(function () {
        db.all('SELECT * FROM fire_violations LIMIT 10',  (error, row) => {
            stmt.push(row)
        })
        res.send (stmt)
    })


})

db.close()```
````

Comment: use await or remove async resolve your problem/

Comment: That didn't resolve the issue but thank you for trying.